# Hex Code Example of Raster Image Print using PCL 5

Tags: image, raster, thermal-printer

Can anyone help me with giving me an example **HEX codes of any Raster Image** pre-setting the Raster Graphics Mode and End Raster Graphics Mode.

A full fledged raster HEX code so that I can pass it to my printer and it prints the data?
Here is the PCL 5 Reference Guide which I am using : [PCL5 Reference Guide](http://www.hp.com/ctg/Manual/bpl13210.pdf)

Any Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my question. Here is an example of Raster Image:

```
\x1B\x2A\x62\x34\x57\x00\x01\x80\x00\x1B\x2A\x62\x34\x57\x00\x01\x80\x00\x1B\x2A\x62\x34\x57\x00\x03\xC0\x00\x1B\x2A\x62\x34\x57\x00\x03\xC0\x00\x1B\x2A\x62\x34\x57\x00\x07\xE0\x00\x1B\x2A\x62\x34\x57\x00\x07\xE0\x00\x1B\x2A\x62\x34\x57\x00\x0F\xF0\x00\x1B\x2A\x62\x34\x57\x00\x0F\xF0\x00\x1B\x2A\x62\x34\x57\x00\x1F\xF8\x00\x1B\x2A\x62\x34\x57\x00\x1F\xF8\x00\x1B\x2A\x62\x34\x57\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\x1B\x2A\x62\x34\x57\x7F\xFF\xFF\xFE\x1B\x2A\x62\x34\x57\x3F\xFF\xFF\xFC\x1B\x2A\x62\x34\x57\x1F\xFF\xFF\xF8\x1B\x2A\x62\x34\x57\x0F\xFF\xFF\xF0\x1B\x2A\x62\x34\x57\x07\xFF\xFF\xE0\x1B\x2A\x62\x34\x57\x03\xFF\xFF\xC0\x1B\x2A\x62\x34\x57\x01\xFF\xFF\x80\x1B\x2A\x62\x34\x57\x00\xFF\xFF\x00\x1B\x2A\x62\x34\x57\x01\xFF\xFF\x80\x1B\x2A\x62\x34\x57\x01\xFF\xFF\x80\x1B\x2A\x62\x34\x57\x03\xFF\xFF\xC0\x1B\x2A\x62\x34\x57\x03\xFE\x7F\xC0\x1B\x2A\x62\x34\x57\x07\xFC\x3F\xE0\x1B\x2A\x62\x34\x57\x07\xF0\x0F\xE0\x1B\x2A\x62\x34\x57\x0F\xE0\x07\xF0\x1B\x2A\x62\x34\x57\x0F\x80\x01\xF0\x1B\x2A\x62\x34\x57\x1F\x00\x00\xF8\x1B\x2A\x62\x34\x57\x1C\x00\x00\x38\x1B\x2A\x62\x34\x57\x38\x00\x00\x1C\x1B\x2A\x62\x34\x57\x30\x00\x00\x0C
```

This above is raster Hex codes for a Star Image.[image: 1]]

**Note**: This hex code will only work with PCL printers to print Star Image.